# Eclipse & adb Not Recognizing Glass as Running Android Device

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, google-glass, google-gdk

So I have a physical Google Glass device attached to my laptop running Windows 8. In Windows Explorer it shows an attached 'Glass 1' device. However when I run a Hello Glass test project in the 'Android Device Chooser' in Eclipse there are no selectable running Android devices. Similarly when I run adb through command prompt, 'adb devices' brings up an empty list of attached devices.

What is the issue here and how can I get Eclipse/adb to see the Glass device?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've been through this very issue multiple times over the last few days (doing some Glass dev work for my company). What you're going to want to do is this:

1. If you haven't yet, install the Google USB Driver package from the Android SDK manager.
2. Open the Device Manager, find the device that's showing up as Glass 1, right click, select "Update Driver Software..."
3. Browse for the drivers, navigate to [Android install folder]\android-sdk\extras\google\usb_driver, click next.
4. Let it install the drivers. If the device is now showing up as "Android Composite ADB Interface", you're good to go and it should appear in adb (assuming you enabled debug on the device itself). If it's just showing up as "Android ADB Interface" without the "Composite", uninstall the drivers, making sure to check the "Delete the driver software..." checkbox, unplug/replug the device, and go back to step 2.

*Disclaimer: I've done all my dev work on Windows 7, so this may not be 100% accurate for Windows 8.*

Answer (score 1):

I struggled for quite a few hours getting Glass recognized by adb in Windows 7.  The two answers above contain essential info, but for me one additional step was necessary:

**turn off automatic driver installation in Windows**

Computer -> Properties -> Advanced system settings -> Hardware -> Device Installation Settings -> "Do you want Windows to download driver software and realistic icons for your devices?" -> "No, let me choose what to do" -> "Never install driver software from Windows Update"

Then, delete the existing driver and reinstall from the adk directory as above.  Before I had changed the driver installation setting, Windows had been installing its idea of the "best driver" as soon as the device was connected and refusing to replace when I attempted to update with the real Google driver.

You're on the right track if Glass shows up under "Other devices" after removing the existing driver, and if it shows as "Android **Composite** ADB Interface" after installing from the android sdk extras directory.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks this step was essential for me to make it work