# Google Glass unknown for Eclipse(Android Device Chooser)

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, google-glass

I know there are a few threads regarding the the connectivity between Google Glasses and Eclipse on Windows 7> but I think mine it's a bit different unfortunately.

I followed this threads:

[Eclipse & adb Not Recognizing Glass as Running Android Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646635/eclipse-adb-not-recognizing-glass-as-running-android-device)

[Unable to connect to Google Glass on Windows 7 (using ADT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21564973/unable-to-connect-to-google-glass-on-windows-7-using-adt)

but unfortunately non helped me 100%.

The PROBLEM:

Even though I followed the steps from the threads, when I go to eclipse and try to run the sample Compass application it shows in the Android Device Chooser(Run configurations) in the target section as unknown.

I must mention that:

1. enabled debugging on the glasses (several times)
2. In the Device Manager(Windows 7) it appears as Android Composite ADV Interface, under SAMSUNG Android Phone(?? on the threads they say that should be Android Devices; anyways it appears as ADV Interface)
3. Reboot system
4. SDK: GoogleUSB Driver(version 10)

What am I missing here? Thanks a lot for every tip! ;)

Comment: Try to uninstall your driver on the Device Manager and then connect your glasses through USB again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ./adb devices ? what do you see when you do that?
Did you confirm that your computer is a trusted device on Glass?